# setting a cookie for img or background img url - images are on a differentDomain

Tags: javascript, cookies

How do you set a cookie or a certain header for requests like:

```
<img src="differentDomain"/>
```

or

```
.className{ background: url(differentDomain); }
```

When I set cookie for my domain and the url of the images are same domain the header is set with cookie fine.

however when the image url is for a different domain I get a problem.

Comment: you can't set a cookie with javascript to a different origin, that origin has to issue it.

Comment: How about from a subdomain to domain ?

Comment: you can't go up but i think you can go down.

Comment: daniel its seems since 2012 you can go both ways